# Enable gRPC verbose logs for Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: grpc, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, grpc-go

I am observing so many gossip related issues across Hyperledger Fabric v2.4.7 network peers. To know the root cause I have enabled the verbose gRPC logs as per [go-grpc official doc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go#how-to-turn-on-logging).
I configured these environment variables along with all the required peer envs:

```
$ export GRPC_GO_LOG_VERBOSITY_LEVEL=99
$ export GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL=info
```

But I still don't see any gRPC verbose logs being printed in the terminal.

(however, I am able to get verbose gRPC logs in terminal if I set these envs for any of other gRPC client/server GO applications)